# extracting class name of first div element using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a couple of div elements as string, is there any way to extract the name of the class of the first div element ? I tried (#element).attr('class'). it does not yield results,may be because it is a string.here is the sample div. PLease note that , it has just div tags and the type of the whole structure is  string

`<div class="some class" ><div class="inner div"></div></div>`

I want "some class" value. The typeof this whole thing is a string.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In otherwords, you have the above text, and you want to extract `some class` from it.

Comment: yes,it can contain white spaces, is there any way to convert it to a html dom ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = '<div class="some class" ><div class="inner div"></div></div>';
console.log($(str).eq(0).attr('class'));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NjejP/)**

Comment: what if they are two seperate divs ?i.e, how can i extract the first one's class name ?

Comment: @parameswar - Can you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: i mean if they were like this :<div class="xy"></div><div class="mm"></div>, so if i want to take the first div class name

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

this is your example, for extract the first div use

alert($("div:first").attr("class"));

Comment: where are we selecting the element here ?